# Mongoose updating document with findOne() matches only wrong results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of `fixtures` that 'belong' to a competitor and look something like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59dbdf6dbe628df3a80419bc"
    },
    "timeOfEntrance": "1507581805813",
    "timeOfFinish": null,
    "competitor": {
        "$oid": "59db5a3f3d6119e69911a61a"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

My goal is to update only the document's `timeOfFinish` by sending a `PUT` request with competitor's ID as a param in the url and timestamp in the body. However I'm struggling to compose the update query.

The following is what I have currently, it never finds the right match and to my surprise it's **always updating the wrong document**.

```
fixtureController.put = (req, res) => {
  const competitorId = req.params.id;
  const timeOfFinish = req.body.timeOfFinish;

  Fixture.findOne({'competitor.$oid': competitorId}, (err, fixture) => {
    fixture.set({ timeOfFinish });

    fixture.save()
      .then(updatedFixture => {
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          fixture: updatedFixture
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: err
        });
      });
  });
};
```

Bit of a beginner in the MongoDB field, will appreciate your comments and solutions.

Comment: Not sure if mongoose supports extended json. Try `Fixture.findOne({'competitor._id': competitorId}` instead

Comment: @Veeram That doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was no need to specify the exact field in the match parameter. Mongoose matches by the id field automatically.

```
Fixture.findOne({'competitor': competitorId}, (err, fixture) => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: FWIW, you can also use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).